# K-mean Clustering R-Tree boost

Tags: c++, boost, k-means, boost-geometry, r-tree

I'm using [R-Tree boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree.html). I added a hundred thousand points in r-tree boost. Now I want to cluster and group my points like this [link](https://blog.mapbox.com/clustering-millions-of-points-on-a-map-with-supercluster-272046ec5c97). It seems like that I should calculate k-mean value from points. How is it possible to calculate k-mean value from r-tree points geometry.

Comment: There's a sample under Boost Compute https://github.com/boostorg/compute/blob/master/example/k_means.cpp

Comment: Kmeans is not well suited for geo coordinates. Use DBSCAN or OPTICS with *haversine* distance. Because earth is not flat.

Comment: @sehe thank you for your reply, it's good but it's on openCV. I don't want to use openCV

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Yes, I think It doesn't matter in my case

Comment: Don't guess, but verify. Distortion is pretty big usually.

Comment: you're right @Anony-Mousse, I don't deny it.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Earth is neither flat nor a sphere. Haversine is more accurate than euclidean distance but it's still an approximation.

Comment: @Behzad There are not clustering algorithms in Boost.Geometry so if you want to use the algorithm you mentioned you have to implement it by yourself. You can of course use R-tree to speed up searching of points in space.

I guess you could treat the R-tree structure itself as the solution of clustering problem since nodes of the R-tree represents clusters of other nodes and geometries. There are papers covering this subject but I don't know how good would it be in practice.

For that you'd have to traverse the internal structure of the R-tree. It's possible but not covered in docs.

Comment: Haversine is usually the best trade-off between accuracy and runtime. Euclidean is horribly inaccurate, and Vincentys spheroidal approximation yields only minor gains in accuracy, that do not matter for real problems (because of mountains, etc. having more effect than the spheroidal approximation vs. the spherical approximation).

Comment: This paper uses geodetic distance with the r-tree. But it is paywalled, I don't know if it only works for Cosine or Haversine or Vincentys. https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-40235-7_9

Comment: @Anony-Mousse The desired accuracy depends on application. Euclidean may be enough in some cases and in other cases even "classic" vincenty may be not enough. What's missing from you is an example use-case you're talking about. E.g. if you want to calculate the distance to a nearest shop and the nearest shop is 100m away euclidean will be enough. However if you want to calculate the distance on a path to a port on the other side of the globe then haversine won't be enough. Note that in the latter case you also don't have mountains. This is also true for planes at 10km. All "real problems".

Comment: @Behzad If you're concerned with accuracy have a look at the tables here: https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/pull/431 You can find there accuracies and performance measurements of various formulas used to calculate distances.

Comment: No, even at 100m Euclidean will *not* just be enough, if you are not at the Equator. At New York, your distortion will be like 30% if I recall correctly. With weighted Euclidean you can do okay, but computing the exact weight is almost as expensive as a good spherical approach.

Comment: This is a great answer detailing the errors you can get from the spherical approximation (about 0.3%): https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/25580/10154 which is usually *much* less than the imprecision cause by buildings, traffic, wind, GPS errors, elevation, ...

Comment: So either the spherical approximation is good enough (because you care about short distances), or you should use a full height, wind, road network, etc. model and not some geometric calculation.

Comment: Again, this depends on application what you'll use or won't use. Besides, this is not a matter of choice. In GPS app you'll have to use roads by definition. In marine application you won't have roads or buildings.

Comment: Marine apps are sensitive to wind, drift, currents. Pretending you need more than 0.3% precision with at least one continent inbetween you and the target... No. That is not precision, that is illusion. Even tide has more effect than the difference between spherical and spheroid (not that spheroid is much slower to compute - it just doesn't get you anything in actual result quality, it's not real precision)

Comment: I agree that spherical is a good approximation if you have geographic coordinates. Cartesian distance is typically calculated if you have data in form of a map projection or after localy-flat approximation.

Comment: And I see really bad 30% errors all the time because people compute flat, unweighted Euclidean, times equatorial radius / 360.

Comment: And if you take all of these factors into account then which distance calculation formula you'll use? Still spherical adding the inaccuracy which you just wanted to minimise?

Btw, you seem to like Karney's answer about the error on sphere. Then here have his proposal about increasing the distance accuracy in Boost.Geometry: https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/issues/449 because currently Andoyer formula is used by default (it's still better than haversine).

Comment: This is why cartesian distance is caluclated after map projection or locally-flat approximation. I never said you should calculate it using raw geographic coordinates.

Comment: Btw, with all of this said in this comments section. I don't see anywhere that the author of the question wants to calculate separation on the globe. AFAIU he may be talking about e.g. an image and simply be dealing with cartesian points.

Comment: (and the question is about kmeans. Kmeans minimizes dx²+dy², you'd need to fix the *mean* with a proper center of mass computation to make it work correctly on a sphere... In particular, it will fail badly at the date line.)

Comment: If I understand correctly you're assuming he's dealing with raw geographic data because of the link he pasted is about MapBox. So:
1. This is not obvious, he may want to use only the clustering algorithm from there but is not dealing with geographic points at all.
2. Even if he was dealing with geographic points the coordinates in the article are after web mercator (spherical) projection, so they are in cartesian, this seems to be good enough for them.

Comment: It's not clear if and what projection they're using exactly. They use webmercator for rendering of tiles.
EDIT: However in the sourcecode they have functions converting between geo coordinates and spherical mercator and other refering tiles so my guess would be that this is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various clustering algorithms having different properties and inputs. What needs to be considered before choosing an algorithm is what do you want to achieve. k-means referred by you in the question aims to partition set of points into k clusters. So the input is the desired number of clusters. On the other hand, the algorithm described in the blog you linked, a variant of greedy clustering algorithm aims to partition set of points into circular clusters of some size. The input is the radius of the desired cluster.

There are various algorithms performing k-means clustering used for different data and applications like separating 2 n-dimensional subsets with hyperplane or clustering with Voronoi diagram (Lloyd's algorithm) often called k-means algorithm. There are also density-based clustering algorithms mentioned by @Anony-Mousse in the comments under your question.

In the article, you mentioned it's a hierarchical version of greedy clustering. They have to calculate the clusters for multiple zoom levels and to avoid analyzing all of the points each time they use the centroids of clusters from the previously analyzed level as a source of points for clustering for the next level. However, in this answer, I'll show how to implement this algorithm for one level only. So the input will be a set of points and a size of cluster as a radius. If you need hierarchical version you should calculate centroids of the output clusters and use them as the input of the algorithm for the next level.

Using Boost.Geometry R-tree the algorithm for one level (so not hierarchical) could be implemented like this (in C++11):

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>

#include <boost/range/adaptor/indexed.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point_t;
typedef bg::model::box<point_t> box_t;
typedef std::vector<point_t> cluster_t;

// used in the rtree constructor with Boost.Range adaptors
// to generate std::pair<point_t, std::size_t> from point_t on the fly
template <typename First, typename Second>
struct pair_generator
{
    typedef std::pair<First, Second> result_type;
    template<typename T>
    inline result_type operator()(T const& v) const
    {
        return result_type(v.value(), v.index());
    }
};

// used to hold point-related information during clustering
struct point_data
{
    point_data() : used(false) {}
    bool used;
};

// find clusters of points using cluster radius r
void find_clusters(std::vector<point_t> const& points,
                   double r,
                   std::vector<cluster_t> & clusters)
{
    typedef std::pair<point_t, std::size_t> value_t;
    typedef pair_generator<point_t, std::size_t> value_generator;

    if (r < 0.0)
        return; // or return error

    // create rtree holding std::pair<point_t, std::size_t>
    // from container of points of type point_t
    bgi::rtree<value_t, bgi::rstar<4> >
        rtree(points | boost::adaptors::indexed()
                     | boost::adaptors::transformed(value_generator()));

    // create container holding point states
    std::vector<point_data> points_data(rtree.size());

    // for all pairs contained in the rtree
    for(auto const& v : rtree)
    {
        // ignore points that were used before
        if (points_data[v.second].used)
            continue;

        // current point
        point_t const& p = v.first;
        double x = bg::get<0>(p);
        double y = bg::get<1>(p);

        // find all points in circle of radius r around current point
        std::vector<value_t> res;
        rtree.query(
            // return points that are in a box enclosing the circle
            bgi::intersects(box_t{{x-r, y-r},{x+r, y+r}})
            // and were not used before
            // and are indeed in the circle
            && bgi::satisfies([&](value_t const& v){
                   return points_data[v.second].used == false
                       && bg::distance(p, v.first) <= r;
            }),
            std::back_inserter(res));

        // create new cluster
        clusters.push_back(cluster_t());
        // add points to this cluster and mark them as used
        for(auto const& v : res) {
            clusters.back().push_back(v.first);
            points_data[v.second].used = true;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<point_t> points;

    for (double x = 0.0 ; x < 10.0 ; x += 1.0)
        for (double y = 0.0 ; y < 10.0 ; y += 1.0)
            points.push_back(point_t{x, y});

    std::vector<cluster_t> clusters;

    find_clusters(points, 3.0, clusters);

    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < clusters.size() ; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Cluster " << i << std::endl;
        for (auto const& p : clusters[i]) {
            std::cout << bg::wkt(p) << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

See also their implementation: https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster/blob/master/index.js#L216

Furthermore, take into account the remarks of @Anony-Mousse about the accuracy of distance calculation on the globe. The solution above is for cartesian coordinate system. If you want to use different coordinate system then you have to define point type differently, e.g. use `bg::cs::spherical_equatorial<bg::degree>` or `bg::cs::geographic<bg::degree>` instead of `bg::cs::cartesian`. You also have to generate the query bounding box differently. But `bg::distance()` will automatically return correct distance after changing the point type.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was looking for an algorithm to separate points by considering closeness. I used the Cartesian coordinate system. I'm lot looking for accurate distance.

Comment: @Behzad I updated the answer with a short intro about various clustering methods. The algorithm which I showed is the greedy clustering from the article, not k-means you mentioned in the question. Are you asking about k-means explicitly? Or are you asking about the algorithm from the article but you're calling it k-means?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts and time, it doesn't matter which method to be used. I was looking for the method to cluster targets on the map. I mentioned k-means value because it's density-based clustering algorithm (I'm not sure) and capable of determining the number of clusters you need.